Stability of perturbation of an elliptic problem into a parabolic PDE
Fix some $f\in H^1(\partial (0,1)^d)$.
Let $\eta\ge 0$ and for each such $\eta$ consider the solution $u^{\eta}$ to the solution PDE
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u & = u_t - \eta u_{tt} \mbox{ on } \mathbb{R}^d\times[0,T] \\
u(x,T)& =f(x) \mbox{ on }\mathbb{R}^d.
\end{cases}
$$
Are there any stability bounds for
$$
\|u^{\eta}-u^0\|_{L^2(0,1)^d}\le \mbox{ some function of }\eta \mbox{ and of }  \|f\|_{H^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}?
$$

This is too many boundary conditions when $\eta=0$. So as it stands, the problem is not properly formulated.

Really I would only want that $u(x,T)=f(x)$ for some smooth function f on $\mathbb{R}^d$, not sure what the boundary condition for the corresponding elliptic problem should be tbh...

I don't understand your notation. If $f$ is only defined on the boundary of the unit cube, how can you have $u=f$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$? In any case, the first approach to such a problem would be to take the Fourier transform with respect to $x$, possibly even starting in 1d for simplicity. This gives you a bunch of independent ODEs which can be explicitly solved and will tell you a lot about the behaviour and about what initial and boundary conditions could work.

@mlk I fixed this, but I still have not managed to find pertrubation bounds.
